# Custom receive timeout for nack with SQS using JMS

Tags: java, amazon-sqs

The behavior of negative acknowledgment is to change the visibility timeout of a received message to 0. Where the value of NACK_TIMEOUT is not configurable while creating the SQS Factory for JMS.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/acknowledge/NegativeAcknowledger.java#L99

When a message is received, and the processing fails (Listener method throws an error), the message is immediately received again. In most of the cases, the message can be processed with a certain delay.

Is it possible to configure it to not change the visibility timeout, so it respects the Queue's default Receive Timeout configuration?

Comment: Copy on Github Issue - https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/issues/75

Comment: That `NegativeAcknowledger` is used in bulk operation. You can use base class instead. Personally I don't get what this question is about. Maybe some details, or kind of example? That can move answering forward.

Comment: related - https://stackoverflow.com/a/64394381/2251411

Answer (score 4):

Apparently there is a way, somewhat clunky, but I didn't find any better workaround, the idea is that when you create client you can attach your own request handler:

```
    return AmazonSQSAsyncClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRequestHandlers(new RequestHandler2() {
            @Override
            public AmazonWebServiceRequest beforeExecution(AmazonWebServiceRequest request) {
                if (request instanceof ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchRequest) {
                    ((ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchRequest) request).getEntries().forEach(changeMessageVisibilityBatchRequestEntry -> {
                        changeMessageVisibilityBatchRequestEntry.setVisibilityTimeout(15);
                    });
                    log.debug("Changed visibility timeout for request {}", request);
                }
                return request;
            }
        })
    ;
```

Answer (score 0):

People who don't want to send `ChangeMessageVisibility` request at all (which reset current visibility timer) and want to rely only on the default queue visibility timeout may use following AmazonSQS wrapper written with the help of lombok:

```java
public AmazonSQS amazonSqs(AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider) {
    AmazonSQS amazonSQS = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion(region)
            (...)
            .build();

    return new IgnoringChangeVisibilityAmazonSqs(amazonSQS);
}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IgnoringChangeVisibilityAmazonSqs implements AmazonSQS {

    private interface ChangeVisibilityOperations {
        ChangeMessageVisibilityResult changeMessageVisibility(ChangeMessageVisibilityRequest changeMessageVisibilityRequest);
        ChangeMessageVisibilityResult changeMessageVisibility(String queueUrl, String receiptHandle, Integer visibilityTimeout);
        ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchResult changeMessageVisibilityBatch(ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchRequest request);
        ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchResult changeMessageVisibilityBatch(String queueUrl, List<ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchRequestEntry> entries);
    }

    @Delegate(excludes = ChangeVisibilityOperations.class)
    private final AmazonSQS amazonSqs;

    @Override
    public ChangeMessageVisibilityResult changeMessageVisibility(ChangeMessageVisibilityRequest changeMessageVisibilityRequest) {
        log.info("Ignoring ChangeMessageVisibilityRequest");
        return new ChangeMessageVisibilityResult();
    }

    @Override
    public ChangeMessageVisibilityResult changeMessageVisibility(String queueUrl, String receiptHandle, Integer visibilityTimeout) {
        log.info("Ignoring ChangeMessageVisibilityRequest");
        return new ChangeMessageVisibilityResult();
    }

    @Override
    public ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchResult changeMessageVisibilityBatch(ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchRequest request) {
        log.info("Ignoring ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchRequest");
        return changeMessageVisibilityBatch(request.getQueueUrl(), request.getEntries());
    }

    @Override
    public ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchResult changeMessageVisibilityBatch(String queueUrl, List<ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchRequestEntry> entries) {
        log.info("Ignoring ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchRequest");
        List<ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchResultEntry> results = entries.stream().map(request ->
                new ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchResultEntry().withId(request.getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ChangeMessageVisibilityBatchResult().withSuccessful(results);
    }
}
```